# Does the Dirichlet eigenvalue problem make sense on a sphere?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, laplacian, spherical-harmonics

The Dirichlet eigenvalue problem on a given suitable domain $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ asks one to find such function(s) $u$ and eigenvalue(s) $\lambda$ that

$$\begin{cases}\Delta u &= \lambda u\text{, in interior of $\Omega$}\\\ u &= 0\text{, on $\partial \Omega$}\end{cases}$$

with $\Delta$ being an appropriate version of the Laplace-Beltrami operator on $\Omega$. In the case of the unit sphere $S^2$, it has been shown that the only eigenfunctions of spherical Laplacian, given in the angular coordinates $(\theta, \phi)\in \left(0, 2\pi\right)\times \left(0, \pi\right)$ as

$$\Delta f = (\sin(\theta))^{-1}\left(\left(\sin(\theta)f_\theta\right)_\theta + \left(\sin(\theta)\right)^{-1}f_{\phi\phi}\right)$$

are the functions

$$f_{m,n}\left(\theta, \phi\right) = \exp(im\phi)P_n^m\left(\cos(\theta)\right), n \in\mathbb{N}, -n\leq m\leq n$$

with

$$P_n^m(x) = i^m\frac{\Gamma(n + m + 1)}{\pi\Gamma(n + 1)}\int_0^\pi\left(x + \sqrt{x^2 - 1}\cos(\phi)\right)^n\cos(m\phi)d\phi$$

Well, as the $\exp$ function never vanishes, $f_{m,n}(\theta, \phi) = 0$ if and only if $P_n^m\left(\cos(\theta)\right) = 0$. But then $f_{m,n}$s can only vanish on some points of the boundary of $\left(0, 2\pi\right)\times \left(0, \pi\right)$ and not for all. So does the Dirichlet eigenvalue problem make sense on the sphere $S^2$? I am not asking this as an attempt to show any "paradoxy", but rather as an honest attempt to understand whether one can faithfully talk about the original Dirichlet eigenfunction problem on a manifold such as the sphere $S^2$.

Comment: It makes sense for $\Omega \subset S^{n-1}$, in which case you can find eigenfunctions but they are not the functions you wrote down. Those are eigenfunctions of the entire sphere (where the eigenvalue problem makes sense, but "Dirichlet" is meaningless: there's no boundary condition needed).

Comment: @user378654 Given that the unit sphere can be parametrized w.r.t. two angular parameters $\theta, \phi$, could the boundary of the parameter space act as the boundary appearing in the Dirichlet eigenvalue problem?

Comment: The boundary is empty, so any Dirichlet conditions is vacuously true. The only condition is periodicity in $\theta$ and $\phi$ to ensure the eigenfunctions are smooth and form a complete basis. Additionally, I believe that eigenfunctions can be constructed with an increasing number of roots in both $\theta$ and $\phi$ using linear combinations of $f_{m,n}$ within the same eigenspace, like combining $e^{i\theta}$ and $e^{-i\theta}$ to get $\sin\theta$. Both of the eigenfunction factors come from Sturm-Liouville problems so they are guaranteed to have increasingly many roots as $m,n\to\infty$.